# Looking for a concept: each decision must be looked at as if it were taken an infinite number of times

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for a concept to which I had been exposed during some sort of Philosophy 101 class. The details that I remember (perhaps erroneously) are the following:

- The core idea is that each decision must not be looked at as an isolated decision, but as an infinite number of identical decisions. E.g. faced with an isolated decision (should I smoke a cigarette or not), my reasoning should not be that I can afford to smoke it *this one time* (after all, one cigarette causes no harm); but that I am taking the decision to smoke *all* the cigarettes *every time I am faced with the same decision*.
- In my mind, I have expanded it to something that sounds like the Golden Rule (do unto others as you would have them do unto you) by admitting that each decision is taken not once for me, but an infinite number of time for everyone. An example would be: I won't throw *my* garbage in the street *once*, because that is the same as *everyone* throwing their garbage in the street *at every occasion, forever*. But I am not sure this expansion was included in the original idea.
- I thought this concept was linked to Aristotle, but I might be confusing with an algorithm called the sieve of Eratosthenes.

Anyone have any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you mean the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)? [Aritosphanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristophanes) was a comedian. You maybe thinking of Kant's [categorical imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_imperative)?

Comment: 1. Yes I did... I even looked it up when writing the question and still somehow got it wrong.

2. That does sound a lot like it, at least under its first formulation. This does surprise me a bit, because I was entirely convinced that it was an ancient philosopher. But unless someone finds an ancient philosopher who did say the same thing, I think this will have to be the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: Surely, this concept must only apply to some types of decisions, not each one. If you are trying to decide whether to get married, for example, would you assume you were going to do that multiple times?

Comment: Isn't it just "act on principle?"